# Neo4j - Filter relationships among nodes

Tags: twitter, neo4j, cypher, nodes, relationship

I've got this kind of relationships:

[image]

I'd like to count and then compute the average of all the incoming relationship to `:Tweet` nodes, excluding the `()-[:POSTS]-()` relationship.
How should I do this properly? So far, I can run this query which computes the average on all the incoming relationships:

```
match (t:Tweet)-->(topic:Topic) 
with topic, size((t)<--()) as rel 
where topic.name='politics' 
return avg(rel) as Avg_RelationshipCount
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refactored form of @sirdan's answer should be much faster:

```
MATCH ()-[r:REPLIES_TO|:RETWEETS]->(:Tweet)-->(topic:Topic)
WHERE topic.name='politics'
WITH topic, COUNT(r) as rel
RETURN AVG(rel) AS Avg_RelationshipCount;
```

The above query filters by `topic.name` *before* generating the relationship count, to eliminate superfluous counting. It also avoids unnecessarily performing the `(t)<-[:REPLIES_TO|:RETWEETS]-()` query twice.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a user who deleted his answer, I found out the solution (with a slight correction to his query):

```
match ()-[:REPLIES_TO|:RETWEETS]->(t:Tweet)-->(topic:Topic) 
with topic, size((t)<-[:REPLIES_TO|:RETWEETS]-()) as rel 
where topic.name='politics' 
return avg(rel) as Avg_RelationshipCount
```

Comment: Hi @sirdan. I have deleted my answer to fix some points in the Cypher query and undelete it after. Happy that you have found a solution! :) You are welcome!

Comment: Yes it helped! Thanks!